# Quotes Within a Variable Within a Sub-Shell

Tags: shell, quotes, subshell

So here's a strange issue I've encountered; I have a script that's trying to build a set of commands to run via `eval`, and these need to run within a sub-shell as part of a bunch of other commands (so I can run them asynchronously). These commands include quotations to protect values with spaces etc. inside, however they're being treated as if the quotations aren't there at all.

For example:

```
cmd="echo 'Foo Bar'"
$(eval "$cmd" | sort) &
```

Results an error of "Foo: command not found"

While running it more directly works fine like-so:

```
eval "$cmd" | sort
```

I realise the example isn't very interesting, but what I don't understand is why the quotations are being lost and how to avoid it, while still executing in a proper sub-shell (with and without processing in the background).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to drop the `$` , `$(eval "$cmd" | sort) &` causes bash to attempt to execute the output from a [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)

Try `(eval "$cmd" | sort) &` instead

Comment: Ah, I see the problem; so the command is executing just fine, it's just dumping the echoed string into the background task, rather than running in the background itself, I think I've got it now, thanks!